# How can I have verbose ansible logs and keep the console output non-verbose?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to save detailed (verbose) ansible logs to files (ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH) but at the same time keep the console output brief.

How can I achieve this? So far I was able to use this approach for saving logs to new files but it seems that they have the same level of verbosity as the console which doesn't help too much.

```
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ]; do # resolve $SOURCE until the file is no longer a symlink
  DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
  SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"
  [[ $SOURCE != /* ]] && SOURCE="$DIR/$SOURCE" # if $SOURCE was a relative symlink, we need to resolve it relative to the path where the symlink file was located
done
DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"

export ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH="$DIR/ansible-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).log"

ansible -m ping localhost
```

Comment: Did you figure this out and have a sample script to share?

Answer (score 7):

Out of the box Ansible just mirrors your console output to ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH.
See `display` method [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/utils/display.py#L138).

Seems the only way to achieve what you want is to make your own callback plugin that write entries to file with maximum verbosity.

For example, you can clone [default.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/default.py) replacing all `self._display.display` to `file.write` and ignore all `self._display.verbosity` checks, so your plugin will ignore `-v` cli switch.